# Delete defined key names from array of object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is my dataFilter. On basis of this I am trying to remove keys from my data.
I want to remove keys that are mentioned in `responseKeys` and `ratings` array.

I am stuck and unable to remove keys from ratings array. Is there any way I can do recursion for this problem.

```js
let dataFilter = {
  "webPage1": {
    "responseKeys": ["releaseDate", "filmName"]
  },
  "webPage2": {
    "responseKeys": ["releaseDate", "ratings"],
    "ratings": [
      "star2",
      "star3"
    ]
  }
}
let data = [{
    "filmName": "Avatar",
    "releaseDate": "2021-09-24",
    "day": "24",
    "month": "Sep",
    "ratings": [{
        "star1": "40",
        "star2": "23",
        "star3": "56",
        "star4": "45"
      },
      {
        "star1": "40",
        "star2": "23",
        "star3": "56",
        "star4": "45"
      },
      {
        "star1": "40",
        "star2": "23",
        "star3": "56",
        "star4": "45"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "filmName": "Morgan",
    "releaseDate": "2021-03-24",
    "day": "24",
    "month": "Mar",
    "ratings": [{
        "star1": "40",
        "star2": "23",
        "star3": "56",
        "star4": "45"
      },
      {
        "star1": "40",
        "star2": "23",
        "star3": "56",
        "star4": "45"
      },
      {
        "star1": "40",
        "star2": "23",
        "star3": "56",
        "star4": "45"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const filterResponse = (data, dataFilter = '') => {
  if (dataFilter) {
    let filterArray = [];
    data.forEach((item) => {
      let response = Object.keys(item)
        .filter(key => dataFilter.responseKeys.includes(key))
        .reduce((obj, key) => {
          obj[key] = item[key];
          return obj;
        }, {});
      filterArray.push(response);
    });
    return filterArray;
  }
  return data;
};

console.log(filterResponse(data, dataFilter['webPage1']));
```

trying to filter my data depending upon my json config.

Expected Output

```
//webPage1
[{
    "filmName": "Avatar",
    "releaseDate": "2021-09-24"
  },
  {
    "filmName": "Morgan",
    "releaseDate": "2021-03-24"
  }
]

//webPage2
[{
    "releaseDate": "2021-09-24",
    "ratings: [{
    "star2": "23",
    "star3": "56"
  },
  {
    "star2": "23",
    "star3": "56"
  },
  {
    "star2": "23",
    "star3": "56"
  }
]
}, {
  "releaseDate": "2021-03-24",
  "ratings": [{
    "star2": "23",
    "star3": "56"
  }, {
    "star2": "23",
    "star3": "56"
  }, {
    "star2": "23",
    "star3": "56"
  }]
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Steps

---

I destructure the `filter` argument to seperate the keys that don't need any more filtering (`responseKeys`) from the ones that'll do (like the `ratings`)

```
const filterResponse = (data, { responseKeys, ...dataFilter }) =>
  ...
```

Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop through the `data` and using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the `key`s, I filter through them with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to get the ones you want back.

```
data.map((item) =>
  ...
  Object.entries(item).filter(([key]) => responseKeys.includes(key))
```

Looping through the filtered data again, if that key does not exist in the `dataFilter` var, it doesn't need to be filtered again so return the prop.

```
(...).map((prop) => {
  const [key, value] = prop;
  if (dataFilter[key] === undefined) return prop;
```

Else, I return an array with the key and value which I filter by getting the `key`s and checking if the key is required with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
  return [key, value.map((cur) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(cur).filter(([curKey]) => dataFilter[key].includes(curKey))))];
});
```

I then use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert the `[key, value]` pairs back to objects

```js
let dataFilter = {"webPage1":{"responseKeys":["releaseDate","filmName"]},"webPage2":{"responseKeys":["releaseDate","ratings"],"ratings":["star2","star3"]}};

let data = [{"filmName":"Avatar","releaseDate":"2021-09-24","day":"24","month":"Sep","ratings":[{"star1":"40","star2":"23","star3":"56","star4":"45"},{"star1":"40","star2":"23","star3":"56","star4":"45"},{"star1":"40","star2":"23","star3":"56","star4":"45"}]},{"filmName":"Morgan","releaseDate":"2021-03-24","day":"24","month":"Mar","ratings":[{"star1":"40","star2":"23","star3":"56","star4":"45"},{"star1":"40","star2":"23","star3":"56","star4":"45"},{"star1":"40","star2":"23","star3":"56","star4":"45"}]}];

const filterResponse = (data, { responseKeys, ...dataFilter }) =>
  data.map((item) =>
    Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(item)
        .filter(([key]) => responseKeys.includes(key))
        .map((prop) => {
          const [key, value] = prop;
          if (dataFilter[key] === undefined) return prop;
          return [
            key,
            value.map((cur) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(cur).filter(([curKey]) => dataFilter[key].includes(curKey))))
          ];
        })
    )
  );

console.log(filterResponse(data, dataFilter['webPage2']))
```

Comment: of course, use cases of this code is limited... just try to solve a simple problem to solve much bigger problem...

Answer (score 1):

You tried well, but you did not implement `ratings` filter...

```js
let data = [{ "filmName": "Avatar", "releaseDate": "2021-09-24", "day": "24", "month": "Sep", "ratings": [{ "star1": "40", "star2": "23", "star3": "56", "star4": "45" }, { "star1": "40", "star2": "23", "star3": "56", "star4": "45" }, { "star1": "40", "star2": "23", "star3": "56", "star4": "45" }] }, { "filmName": "Morgan", "releaseDate": "2021-03-24", "day": "24", "month": "Mar", "ratings": [{ "star1": "40", "star2": "23", "star3": "56", "star4": "45" }, { "star1": "40", "star2": "23", "star3": "56", "star4": "45" }, { "star1": "40", "star2": "23", "star3": "56", "star4": "45" }] }]
let filterResponse = (data, dataFilter) => data.map(v => {
    let o = {}
    dataFilter.forEach(item => o[item] = v[item])
    return o
})

console.log("webPage1", filterResponse(data, ["releaseDate", "filmName"]));
console.log("webPage2", filterResponse(data, ["releaseDate", "ratings"]).map(item => {
    item.ratings = filterResponse(item.ratings, ["star2", "star3"])
    return item
}))
```

Comment: Problem is rating is dynamic. That can be in any object or not.

Comment: what do you mean by _"rating is dynamic"_?

Comment: Like for webPage2 you added `map` method. We will not know which object will have rating or not.

Comment: this is not a problem, its just an abstraction... now use that abstraction for your need,